# SQL Server Connection Pools with Prepared Statements and Transactions

Tags: c#, .net, transactions, sql-server-2012, prepared-statement

I'm hoping to leverage connection pooling in my .Net application, but have some concerns about support for prepared statements and transactions. Although it appears that the .Net framework provides the [EnlistTransaction](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.enlisttransaction%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to provide support for transactions with connection pools, I'm trying to determine if similar support exists for prepared statements...or if such support is even required. Does anyone know the answer to this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR - the .Net SQL Server connection pool handles prepared statements seamlessly.

I created a main program to test this...

```
private static void TestPreparedStatement()
{
    const string sql = "INSERT INTO myTable(id, numInt) " +
                       "VALUES((SELECT MAX(id) " +
                               "FROM myTable) + 1, @numInt);";
    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(s_connStr))
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Getting ready to prepare statement on connection with ID " + dbConn.ClientConnectionId);
        s_cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, dbConn);
        s_cmd.Parameters.Add("@numInt", SqlDbType.Int);
        s_cmd.Prepare();
        Console.WriteLine("The command has been prepared.");
    }

    for (int threadNdx = 0; threadNdx < 10; ++threadNdx)
    {
        Thread prepStmntThread = new Thread(ExecPrepStmnt)
        {
            Name = threadNdx.ToString()
        };

        prepStmntThread.Start();
    }
}

private static void ExecPrepStmnt()
{
    using (SqlConnection dbConn = new SqlConnection(s_connStr))
    {
        dbConn.Open();
        lock (s_cmd)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " has ownership of the command.");
            s_cmd.Connection = dbConn;
            s_cmd.Parameters["@numInt"].Value = int.Parse(Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " is about to execute the command on the connection with ID " + s_cmd.Connection.ClientConnectionId + ".");
            try
            {
                s_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " successfully executed the command.");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " failed to execute the command.");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " is about to relinquish ownership of the command.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " is going to sleep with open pooled connection.");
        Thread.Sleep(5 * 1000);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Thread #" + Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.");
}
```

The output was...

```
Getting ready to prepare statement on connection with ID 289ae798-7564-4b7c-b45f-60d09d54fa87
The command has been prepared.
Thread #0 has ownership of the command.
Thread #0 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 289ae798-7564-4b7c-b45f-60d09d54fa87.
Thread #0 successfully executed the command.
Thread #0 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #0 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #2 has ownership of the command.
Thread #2 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 2585e1fb-980a-45ee-9a59-17d94f44b2d5.
Thread #2 successfully executed the command.
Thread #2 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #2 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #1 has ownership of the command.
Thread #1 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 2772d6a2-dc23-472d-bb4e-adfa99e97bdf.
Thread #1 successfully executed the command.
Thread #1 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #1 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #3 has ownership of the command.
Thread #3 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 1ce7f447-f485-4b85-9ede-2854fc160a83.
Thread #3 successfully executed the command.
Thread #3 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #3 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #4 has ownership of the command.
Thread #4 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 62d62a9c-b2e0-42e5-99da-3682cf7614ee.
Thread #4 successfully executed the command.
Thread #4 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #4 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #5 has ownership of the command.
Thread #5 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID cb62e434-534a-49a7-afbd-96e85f7e5888.
Thread #5 successfully executed the command.
Thread #5 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #5 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #6 has ownership of the command.
Thread #6 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 946ccf21-a278-46ad-871f-5030ee00fcd0.
Thread #6 successfully executed the command.
Thread #6 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #6 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #7 has ownership of the command.
Thread #7 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID a4b36316-8f82-44ff-998b-f33b94b34320.
Thread #7 successfully executed the command.
Thread #7 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #7 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #8 has ownership of the command.
Thread #8 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID 11f558a0-128d-4401-94cb-57fff007ae81.
Thread #8 successfully executed the command.
Thread #8 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #8 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #9 has ownership of the command.
Thread #9 is about to execute the command on the connection with ID c613e347-1471-4476-a6d7-1485e2c731c5.
Thread #9 successfully executed the command.
Thread #9 is about to relinquish ownership of the command.
Thread #9 is going to sleep with open pooled connection.
Thread #0 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #2 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #1 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #3 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #4 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #5 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #6 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #7 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #8 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
Thread #9 has woken up and disposed of its pooled connection.
```

So basically it looks like there's nothing to be worried about at all. My boss ran a SQL Server profile on the database server while I was running the test program above, and claimed that he never actually saw a call to `sp_prepare`. Considering the fact that SQL Server caches execution plans, this probably isn't a very big deal.

Unfortunately, since writing my question, I've realized that the SqlConnection.EnlistTransaction method is not as helpful (in my particular circumstance) as I was originally hoping. Due to that fact, it appears that we will have to handle transactions as a special case in my application.

Comment: The recommended, hip new way of dealing with transaction is not to explicitly muck about with them at all but to use `TransactionScope`. Anything within a `TransactionScope` will be enlisted, saving you the trouble of assigning them to connections and commands explicitly (as well as knowing anything about them on the lower levels). The connection pool, meanwhile, is usually the *last* thing you need to worry about -- `SqlConnection` will just "do the right thing" when it comes to getting an existing connection from the pool or creating a new one.

Comment: Right...unfortunately that doesn't work for me. This is a web app and someone will come in with a request to start a transaction, then multiple intermediate requests to execute statements in the context of that transaction, and then, finally, a request to either commit or rollback the transaction. So binding it all in the scope of a single requests execution doesn't work...unless of course I'm missing something.

Comment: Well, it's possible to use a stateful WCF service and tie a transaction to that... but that's very much not recommended because you're at the mercy of the client for the duration of locks. *Any* design where you mix transactions with remote clients is bad almost by definition... but that's going beyond the scope of this question.